# debian/rules error while .deb packaging

Tags: debian, packaging, ubuntu-12.04, deb, debhelper

i'm having some problems creating a .deb file with debuild

before reading some tutorials i managed to make the file but i always get this error:

```
    make: *** No rule to make target «build». Stop.
    dpkg-buildpackage: failure: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
    debuild: fatal error at line 1329:
    dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b failed
```

Any help??

This is my debian rules file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/make -f
    # -*- makefile -*-
    # Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
    # This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
    # As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
    # dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
    # This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

    # Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
    #export DH_VERBOSE=1

    build-stamp: configure-stamp 
        dh_testdir
        touch build-stamp

    clean:
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
        dh_clean

    install: build
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        dh_clean -k 
        dh_installdirs
        $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter
        mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter

        # Copy .py files
        cp pycounter.py $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/pycounter.py
        cp prefs.py $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/prefs.py

        # desktop copyright and others (not complete, check)
        cp extras-pycounter.desktop $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/usr/share/applications/extras-pycounter.desktop
```

Comment: Your install target depends on build, but there is no build in the file you showed.

Comment: I also dont see 'sudo' anywhere http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/make.1.html

Comment: it seems like you removed the catch-all target (%: dh $@) from the debian/rules

Comment: @frank: he is running dpkg-buildpackage with fakeroot; no need to use sudo (man dpkg-buildpackage)

Comment: i fixed the problem, i had to make the file from scratch, but it works, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Please post and accept your answer so this question doesn't come up as requiring an answer still.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it, making a new file from scratch, checking the debian man pages again...